# Automatically advance to the next step

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a software that helps a user to perform one step after another. You can think of it like doing a tutorial. At the moment, each successful step needs to be confirmed by the user after it has been done.

I'd like to provide an option so that the tutorial automatically continues with the next step, when the current step is done.

Is there a nice short single word that would describe such an option?

I thought of `auto-advance`, but I'm not even sure that's a real English word. Also `fast-forward` doesn't seem to be really correct here, because it's still at the speed of the user (real time so to say).

My native language is German, and to be honest, I don't even know a suitable word there, so I can't look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: Would this be an option to enable/disable like a checkbox in the settings or something? If so I think 'auto-advance' is a good fit especially if you have the ability to add a hint when they hover over the option.

Comment: @ChrisR: yes, it would be a checkbox. Hovering (in the sense of a tooltip) is not possible, unfortunately. Would it still be self-explainign enough?

Comment: Hmm..I think it might depend on the user. This could also be a good question for the [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: Auto-advance seems to be accepted terminology in things like slideshows.  The term makes sense to me.

Comment: Another vote for Auto-Advance. Incidentally, 'software' is normally considered a mass-noun in English, so 'a software' strikes a bit of a wrong note. "An application", "a program", "a piece of software" and so on would sound better to a native speaker.

Comment: If this option is available primarily to let users run through the steps in preparation for a culminating, stop-and go sitting, you could perhaps use…[run-through](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run-through) .  If it’s not for that purpose you could consider getting ‘cutesy’ with “Express,” “Non-stop,” or “One-shot” [viewing] for this option and “Stop-and-go” [viewing] for the step-by-step option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments mentioned that **auto-advance** is a valid English word, so we are using it.

We did not use **skip**, because that implied to us that a step is not needed to be performed. That's not the case here: every step has to be performed.

Answer (score 1):

The user would press a **skip button** to auto pass the tutorial. Per *Merriam Webster*:

> **[skip:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skip)**  to pass over or omit an interval, item, or step

[image]

*a **skip** button is used to skip the option of adding a message to facebook.*